# Pannier rack bag for a not suitable suspension fork (Btwin Rockrider 5.1)

Tags: mountain-bike, fork, suspension, panniers

I ride a Btwin Rockrider 5.1 with a baby seat, and want to attach one or two pannier rack bags. I guess I only can put it on the front wheel because of the baby seat which goes over the rear wheel, fixed to my seat tube.
At the store they say I have nothing to do, since this fork is not ready for that kind of accesories (it only has two screw holes for an eventual disk brake).

Is there any kind of rack I can use?

Do I have any chance to put it on the rear wheel under the baby seat?

Comment: What's the baby seat model?

Comment: @jm2 It is Polisport Boodie: http://www.merkabici.es/img/anuncios/7c29470fdfb0b9fbd4219c02e7b616073.jpg

Comment: Im assuming your bike is a hard tail?  Do you have any more eyelets on the rear dropouts for accessories?

Comment: @BPugh Yes, it has no rear suspension. There are these three eyelets (red arrows) on both sides: http://i.imgur.com/lZyiZ82.jpg

Comment: @Rober Is the seat in the photo (the purple part on the left)?  I don't see how it attaches to the bike.  I forgot how large those seats are, a rear rack may not work.  I use a trailer myself.  Are you looking to using both the seat and the panniers at the same time?  If not then you could replace it with the Topeak child seat that has a special rack.  I believe it is a MTX rack so you can get one of the trunk bags with panniers.  Looking at Amazon it will probably be $225 for the setup though.

Comment: @BPugh Yes, the purple thing is the seat. Tahnks for the seat and racks models tip!

Comment: Btwin is a decathlon brand, so I assume there's one in your location. I've bought a small bag to be used on the handlebars since my fork has no eyelets at all

Comment: @k102 that's a good thing to bring up. handlebar bags may be coming back into fashion, including on drop bar bikes! that said, they are much smaller than panniers, so they may not meet the OP's use case. in addition, it's possible the OP could get a top tube frame bag, which has slightly more storage (but may obstruct water bottle cages), or a full frame bag (which completely fill the front triangle, ergo no bottles at all, but you could put a hydration bladder and hose in that bag). these options may have not been available/commonplace at the time the question was asked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While I am not familiar with your bike or its front fork. I would think a front pannier rack like this may work. http://www.zefal.com/en/racks/118-raider-front.html

Please note that weight on the front fork makes the bike even easier to fall over. Please be very careful when the baby is on the back. I am not a fan of rear baby seats and would just buy a trailer.

Comment: Great! I hadn't seen that kind of fixation. I'm looking for local providers (Spain) at that website : )

Comment: Amazon sells it in the US.